# Is there a way to simplify $(x+y)^z$ using only basic functions?

Tags: polynomials

So no Big-O notation, Re(), derivatives, only stuff you could find a scientific calculator.

Comment: What are $x$, $y$, and $z$? Definite numbers? Or do you mean something like a polynomial, say $(x+y)^4$ expanded?

Comment: Without much information about $x,y,z$ a good place to start is at the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations

Comment: Sure, $x^z+zx^{z-1}y +\frac {z(z-1)}{2!}x^{z-2}y^2\ldots +y^z$

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ is a positive whole number, $$(x+y)^z=\sum_{n=0}^{z}{z\choose n}x^{z-n}y^n$$
Where $${z\choose n}=\frac{z!}{n!(z-n)!}$$
If $z$ is not a positive whole number, the formula is a little more complicated. So to answer your question; not really.